# AutoCompleteTextView causes items in ListView to disappear

Tags: android, commonsware

I'm doing the Extra Credit section of the Adding a List section in Android Tutorials. I tried populating the AutoCompleteTextView (ACTV) with the items contained in the ArrayAdapter, but if the addr field has characters in it above the threshold limit, the list doesn't show any items. Here is the code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
List<Restaurant> model = new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
ArrayAdapter<Restaurant> adapter = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(onSave);

    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.restaurants);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Restaurant>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    model);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.addr);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private View.OnClickListener onSave= new View.OnClickListener(){
    ...
};
}
```

And the XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:shrinkColumns="1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Name:"/>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/name"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Address:"/>
        <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/addr"
                              android:completionThreshold="5"
                />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Type:"/>
        <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/types">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/take_out"
                         android:text="Take Out"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:checked="true"
                         />
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/sit_down"
                         android:text="Sit Down"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/delivery"
                         android:text="Delivery"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:text="Save"/>
</TableLayout>
<ListView android:id="@+id/restaurants"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_above="@id/details"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Changing the completionThreshold changes the number of characters I can enter before the items in the List disappear.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to use the same adapter for both the `ListView` and the `AutoCompleteTextView`. That is not a good idea. Please use separate adapters. You might even want a separate layout for the adapter used with the `AutoCompleteTextView` (e.g., `android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line`, as I used in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Selection/AutoComplete)).

Comment: Great that fixes the disappearing items. Can you elaborate on why you need separate adapters? Also, how would you populate the list of suggestions with the data from the list? Right now, it works from hard-coded strings, but not with the data from the list.

Comment: @Richard: "Can you elaborate on why you need separate adapters?" -- because they hold data that needs to be different between the two hosting `AdapterViews`, notably the filter used with your `AutoCompleteTextView`. I cannot help you with the rest given the limited information you provided.

Comment: need help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045738/customadapter-constructor-undefined